# df loc to deselect columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I'm trying to *de*select columns using `df.loc`. I want to select all columns that does not have names that includes e.g. "X".

I can filter the columns with:

```
df.filter(like='X')
```

, but how can I *exclude* them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

array=np.random.random((2,3))
df=pd.DataFrame(array, columns=('X', 'Y', 'Z'))

          X         Y         Z
0  0.101461  0.459929  0.987757
1  0.027182  0.937235  0.045712

df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.contains('X', case=False)]
```

Output:

```
          Y         Z
0  0.459929  0.987757
1  0.937235  0.045712
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`pandas.Index.difference`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html)  :

```
df[df.columns.difference(df.filter(like='X').columns, sort=False)]
```